# Parsing JSON array with JQuery

Tags: javascript, json

I am having the most difficult time parsing the json below using jquery.

```
{ "client": [{"ClientID": "0000000001", "Name": "Valdez Gilberto JR",   "Phone": "(956)542-8148" , "MedActID": "10", "Gender": "M", "Division": "WP", "Address": "1905 Illinois Ave N", "Class": "", "CityState": "Brownsville TX 78521-6732" } , {"ClientID": "0000000002", "Name": "Salazar Olga F", "Phone": "(956)546-3909" , "MedActID": "100", "Gender": "F", "Division": "MP", "Address": "Route 8 Box 626 (San Pedro)", "Class": "", "CityState": "Brownsville TX 78520" } ]}
```

Been using the code below but to no avail, keep getting undefined errors  "data" is being called via ajax:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){
alert(obj[i].client.Name)
}
```

Have even tried the following:

```
$.each(obj, function(key,value) {
 alert(value.client.Name);
});
```

Comment: to be clear.. you're not having any trouble at all "parsing" the json, you're having trouble looping over the resulting object. For some reason you're treating the object as if it were an array.

Comment: How would I correct the issue?  Driving me nuts...  Have even tried

Comment: right... but what makes you think `obj` is an array or has a length? clearly your json represents an object that has a property that contains an array.

Comment: @Dango did it solve ur issue?

Answer (score 2):

You should grab the "client" property first which is an array.
Once you grab it, then you can iterate over it as an array.

```
{                                        //object              | obj
   "client":[                            //property (array)    | obj.client
      {                                  //object inside array | obj.client[0]
         "ClientID":"0000000001",
         "Name":"Valdez Gilberto JR",    //property            | obj.client[0].Name
         "Phone":"(956)542-8148",
         "MedActID":"10",
         "Gender":"M",
         "Division":"WP",
         "Address":"1905 Illinois Ave N",
         "Class":"",
         "CityState":"Brownsville TX 78521-6732"
      },
      {
         "ClientID":"0000000002",
         "Name":"Salazar Olga F",
         "Phone":"(956)546-3909",
         "MedActID":"100",
         "Gender":"F",
         "Division":"MP",
         "Address":"Route 8 Box 626 (San Pedro)",
         "Class":"",
         "CityState":"Brownsville TX 78520"
      }
   ]
}
```

This code will iterate over the objects inside the "client" property, and alert the names.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
var client = obj.client; //client prop is an array
for(var i = 0; i < client.length; i++){
  alert(client[i].Name);
}
```

Comment: Worked Great Thanks! was missing "obj.client" !

Comment: @Dango don't forget to upvote/accept as answer, if the answer solves your question

Comment: Again, if you downvote, give feedback why. This solved the question @Dango was having so I don't see any issue here.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to iterate an object, but you can't do that. What you want is to iterate trough the array which is in your object, keyed by `client`

Try this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < obj.client.length; i++){
    console.log(obj.client[i].Name)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to iterate through an object. `obj.client` is the Array you are looking for.

```js
var data = '{ "client": [{"ClientID": "0000000001", "Name": "Valdez Gilberto JR",   "Phone": "(956)542-8148" , "MedActID": "10", "Gender": "M", "Division": "WP", "Address": "1905 Illinois Ave N", "Class": "", "CityState": "Brownsville TX 78521-6732" } , {"ClientID": "0000000002", "Name": "Salazar Olga F", "Phone": "(956)546-3909" , "MedActID": "100", "Gender": "F", "Division": "MP", "Address": "Route 8 Box 626 (San Pedro)", "Class": "", "CityState": "Brownsville TX 78520" } ]}';
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
for (var i = 0; i < obj.client.length; i++) {
  console.log(obj.client[i].Name);
}
```

Comment: if you downvote, leave a comment why? this works perfectly!!